# Performance tip: x% of this request was spent in waiting

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

When reviewing Application Insights for slow API requests I noticed a message stating: "98.49% of this request was spent in waiting.". I'm finding next to no explanation about this online.

1. What does this mean? What is it waiting for?
2. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights collects performance details for the different operations in your application. By identifying those operations with the longest duration, you can diagnose potential problems or best target your ongoing development to improve the overall performance of the application.

The **Performance Tip** at the top of the screen supports the assessment that the **`excessive duration`** is due to waiting. Click the waiting link for documentation on interpreting the different types of events.

[image]

These are all indication of slow server operations.

You can read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-performance). Also please look for the event which is causing waiting time duration and then work accordingly.

Let me know if you need any help related to fix perf issue.